# Can't override CSS for font color

Tags: css, drupal-7

My CSS skills are pretty beginner...
I'm unable to override the font color for a link. I want the font color for the link with class="button2" to be white but it stays blue no matter what I try. How can I get the 'color' in my button2 style to be respected?
(it is a Drupal 7 site with UberCart)

Here is the style:

```css
.button2 {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  /*background: #4479BA;*/
  background: #00CC66;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /*border: solid 1px #20538D;*/
  border: solid 1px #003319;
  /*text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);*/
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(121, 121, 121, 0.4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Firebug shows this CSS from another style sheet that appears to be overriding my style

```css
a:link, a:visited, a:active, a.active, li a.active {
  color:#2079d2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add this?

```
color: #FFF !important;
```

The important part makes it override the other stuff.

Comment: Had tried that but I had an extra semicolon 'color: #fff; !important;' so wasn't working. I was hoping there was a way to do it without using !important?